# Cannot change the variable in Angular js, why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

can you help please.
I have found this example in Fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/terebentina/9mFpp/

My question, why in Angular(in this example)

```
$scope.widget = {title: 'abc'}; // works very well and ...
$scope.widget.title = 'abc'; // doesn't work
```

This is property of an object in Javascript(widget.title). I always thought - we can set it anytime? where I am wrong?

Comment: did you create widget first?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9mFpp/1523/

Answer (score 2):

`$scope` is an Object, but `$scope.widget` is undefined until it is set. You can either initialise it as an Object first, and then set properties, like this:

```
$scope.widget = {};
$scope.widget.title = 'abc';
```

Or you can do as the fiddle does and initialise it while initialising properties at the same time:

```
$scope.widget = {title: 'abc'};
```

Comment: I really hope more and more people would spend sometime learn JavaScript more. Too much people know too little about it yet working with it... Nice one.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the second doesn't work is because you need to initialize the object first:

```
// initialize the object first
$scope.widget = {};

// and now you can set the title
$scope.widget.title = 'abc';
```

but this makes you type 2 lines of code. It is a bit shorter to do those 2 things directly:

```
// Initialize the widget object and set its title property
$scope.widget = {title: 'abc'};
```

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work becasue the widget object is not defined(not exists yet)

Following code creates an object(containing field 'title' with value 'abc') and assigns it to '$scope.widget' variable:

```
$scope.widget = {title: 'abc'};
```

Following code assigns 'abc' into 'title' filed of 'widget' object:

```
$scope.widget.title = 'abc';
```

so in order to work the widget variable must be defined